# Execute VBScript file using HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vbscript, command-prompt

I'm trying to Execute the following .vbs file using HTML. But it is not executing this. When i'm executing the .vbs file using command promt, it is working. But while trying to execute from HTML, it is not working.

demo.vbs file

```
Dim IE
 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Visible = 1 
 IE.navigate "http://testingwebpage/web"
 Do While (IE.Busy)
   WScript.Sleep 10
 Loop 
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0)
Helem.Click
WScript.Sleep 10000
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("searchOptions_listbox").getElementsByTagName("li")(3)
Helem.Click
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("orderNumberInput")
 Helem.Value="990462"
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(9)
 Helem.Click
```

test.html

```
<html>

<head>
<title>printHello() Function in an Include File</title>

<script type="text/vbscript" src="demo.vbs"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="vbscript:MyFunc()">Click me</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the Answers..!!

Comment: VBScript is disabled in recent versions of IE on non-intranet sites. What version of IE are you using?

Comment: IE version 11 @Tmdean

Comment: Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx, VBS is disabled by default.  The document contains a link that shows how to enable it for now; however, that may not work when the next version of IE is released.

Answer (score 0):

This will not solve your problem, but you are calling a function MyFunc which is not declared (apparently) in the Vbscript

your code should be:

```
Public Function MyFunc
     'your code
End Function
```

written like you did, the code will execute at the page loading, not after clicking the button